# How can I allow users with their own slack account/company login to their slack account in my app

Tags: swift, oauth, slack

Everything I have read (e.g. https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) makes it seem as though I can only build an app that integrates with a Slack team I manage. E.g. I have to create my Slack Client ID .. etc ... and then I can oAuth users for my team.

What I want to do is allow my app's users to login to my app using their Slack login (for their Slack team I do not control or have access to.) I don't want to force my users to generate a Client ID to use my app. I want them to login the same way Google Login or Facebook Login works.

The closest thing I have found is a "login with slack" HTML button, but I'd like to do it in iOS using Swift.

Is that possible?

Comment: this will probably help you. https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-implement-slack-like-login-on-ios-with-auth0/

Comment: Why did I get a down vote? There is no answer to this question on S.O. already, and the docs don't explicitly state if this is possible or not.

Comment: probably because your question was a bit broad and you did not show any source code or something that you have done prior to asking the question. If you have clicked the link above, it might help you. It will lead you to sample source code from Github on how to do it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some help from friends it looks like the answer is yes.

You must first make sure you "Distribute App"

[image]

Then set up the permissions you require and "install app" (which is a bit not "smart" since you can accidentally add conflicting permissions and get an error when trying to install).

[image]

Once that is done you will get an Auth Token and can make requests for any user to login using oAuth.

You can also trigger a sign in request like so:

https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[client id]&scope=identity.basic

**Edit**: For future Googlers, Slack now also provides a specific documentation page for this type of OAuth grant/login: [Sign in with Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, that's not possible. For google or facebook, the way authentication works is that they provide you a mobile API which handles the communication between your app and their web service. So you task is simply adopt that API, make simple function call and retrieve information for user from the API. For example, the *facebook button* is provided by the API.

However from a look at slack site, they only have RESTful API documented. So in this case, you have to handle the passing and storing of parameters by yourself, and send HTTP request manually. You can have a look at Alamofire framework, which is the best choice for making HTTP request. Basically, you have to send needed parameter with the specific url though HTTP request to perform a log in action, and you have to parse the respond data and then see if the login is successful or not, etc

Comment: Thanks @fangming. I'm not to worried about making the requests manually. My concern is that I have to ask the user to input their own Client ID in order for me to hit the API on their behalf. Does that make sense? Is there a way to programmatically create a handshake on their behalf for a Slack team I am not a part of? (whether I do it manually or not)

Comment: @Sean Given that they only a web RESTful API, I don't think that's possible, no

Comment: K. Thanks again for the time and feedback